# Using unplugin-vue-components in a monorepo

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

**Background**

I have a monorepo (Using Turborepo) with multiple apps and packages. All apps are developed using Vue3 with Vite and the `unplugin-vue-components` for automatically importing components from the specific app. I also want to include components from other packages e.g. `ui-base` and `ui-shared`

**Example of apps and packages**

- apps/appX
- apps/appY
- packages/ui-base
- packages/ui-shared

**Question**

Is it possible to configure `unplugin-vue-components` in e.g. `appX` to automatically import my base UI components from `ui-base` package and also prefix them with `V`? Moreover, I want to do the same for `ui-shared` and prefix it with `S`.

Comment: Did you the unplugin-vue-components to work (without the prefixes)? Currently facing the an similar issue

Answer (score 0):

You can add the paths of `ui-base` and `ui-shared` in `vite.config.ts` file to search for vue components. Check this official [doc](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components#configuration) and try adding relative paths in `dirs`.

You can check this [blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-automatically-import-register-vue-components/) for some config customization examples.

Comment: Yes, that I already understand. To elaborate on my question, if a add the paths to `dirs`. How do I prefix them? e.g. all components from `ui-base` with `V` and all components from `ui-shared` with `S`?

Comment: Did you try adding path prefixes in tsconfig file? https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths

Comment: The paths are not the problem. The prefixes for the various paths is

Comment: That is what "paths" used for in tsconfig. Right? For example for your case it will be "paths": { "V" :  [ "../my-path/ui-base/*" ] }

Comment: Now when you import it will be imported from "V/your-component" instead of "ui-base/your-component". I hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, this is the solution for a name alias, not a prefix. I think you want to add prefix like import from "V/ui-base/.." right? My bad!