# Does unplugin-vue-components work in a nx monorepo?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, nx-monorepo

I am **migrating** a monolithic vue3-repository **into a nx-monorepo**.

Before migrating to a monorepo, I had set up my `vite.config.ts` to **auto-import all my vue-components from `src/components`** with ['unplugin-vue-components'](https://github.com/unplugin/unplugin-vue-components).

Then I outsourced all components from `src/components/pr/*` into a **nx-lib**, to use them in other projects as well, resulting in **following structure**:

- apps:

  - main
- libs:

  - pr-components

I then updated my main's `vite.config.ts` to now **auto-import the components from the new lib as well**. But unfortunately **serving the application does not work,** **Vite gets stuck** and does not reply to requests for resources anymore.

My `vite.config.ts` before migrating:

```js
// vite.config.ts 

import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite' 
// ... 

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => { 
  // .... 
  const config = { 
    plugins: [ 
      //... 
      Components({ 
        // allow auto load markdown components under `./src/components/` 
        extensions: ['vue', 'md'], 
        // allow auto import and register components used in markdown 
        include: [/\.vue$/, /\.vue\?vue/, /\.md$/], 
        dts: 'src/components.d.ts', 
      }), 
    ] 
  } 

  return config 
})
```

My new `vite.config.ts` in the `main`-app of the nx-repo:

```js
// main's vite.config.ts 

import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite' 
// ... 
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => { 
  // .... 
  const config = { 
    plugins: [ 
      //... 
      Components({ 
        // allow auto load markdown components under `./src/components/` 
        extensions: ['vue', 'md'], // allow auto import and register components used in markdown 
        include: [/\.vue$/, /\.vue\?vue/, /\.md$/], 
        dts: 'src/components.d.ts', 
        dirs: [ 
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'), 
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../../libs/pr-components/src/components'), 
        ] 
      }), 
    ] 
  } 
  return config 
})
```

I can confirm that `unplugin-vue-components` **does find the Components in the new path** (Vite logs messages, if it finds duplicate component-names for example), but is not evaluating them correctly.

Thus making Vite **serve the application does not work**, but results in Vite getting stuck, not loading requests for resources anymore.

There's a similar post here, but with a slightly different intention: [Using unplugin-vue-components in a monorepo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76120050/using-unplugin-vue-components-in-a-monorepo)

Has anyone successfully achieved a similar setup?